# Query OSM ids by name in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I installed PostGIS on a server and now I want to query the OSM ids referring to a name, in order to get a list of all geometries according to this name.

Is there an efficient way to query this ids in PostGIS or do I have to use a tool like nominatim?

I am new to OSM and PostGIS.

Comment: We'll need more specifics about how your data is stored, what method did you use to import the OSM data?

Comment: I used osm2sql to import the data. For testing I imported the data of germany.

Comment: And when you say you want to query on name, do you have certain kinds of features? An example pulled from the schema documentation: select name, place, ST_XMin(way), ST_YMin(way) 
    from planet_osm_point where place='city' order by name;

Comment: thank you, this works for me. Do are osm_ids in planet_osm_point are equivalent to the osm_ids in planet_osm_polygon?